# SSO implementation betwwen OBIEE and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, obiee

We have application build in asp.net in which on button we need to go to OBIEE dashboard. Similarly need to come back from OBIEE to ASP.NET application.

Currently I am using redirecting from ASP.net page to OBIEE with username and password in the URL. But as per my requirement i need to implement SSO or username and password should not be passed in URL query string.

Please suggest how to implement the it

Thanks

Ankush

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know the precise answer, but here are few steps to implement single sign on (SSO)

create a new user with name 'Impersonator' in RPD.

create table [USER_INFO] with user's details in the DB.

create initialization block siteminder_auth in PRD as below.

'select USER_ID, GROUPNAME, WEBGROUPS, DISPLAYNAME, LOGLEVEL, PORTAL_PATH from USER_INFO where USER_ID=':USER'

Delete all users except 'Administrator' from the 'Presentation Catalog Security' window.

Also few changes need to be done in instanceconfig.xml, one of them is

SSO enabled="true"

Hope this helps :)